A common misinterpretation of transversality being a stable property.
In the first Chapter in Differential Topology by Guillemin Pollack (Section 6:Homotopy and Stability),the authors have asserted that, Transversality is a stable property in the sense that if $X$ is a compact manifold and $Y$ is any manifold and $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth map and if $f\pitchfork Z$,a closed submanifold of $Y$.Then for every homotopy $f_t:X\to Y$ starting at $f_0=f$,there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f_t \pitchfork Z$ for every $t\in [0,\epsilon)$.
But the statement is to be understood carefully and with caution.A common misinterpretation of the statement may arise to a new reader.When I had been studying for the first time I also got a little confused about the meaning of this statement.
The stability statement of Transversality given in the first paragraph means precisely that,if some function is transversal to a submanifold in the codomain and if the function is homotoped in any given way,then there is always a small enough perturbation of time parameter $t$(which is $\epsilon$) that allows preserving the transversality.
For example if we take the submanifold $Z= \{(x,0):x\in \mathbb R\}$ of $Y=\mathbb R^2$ which is the $x$axis and then we take $f:S^1\to \mathbb R^2$ to be $f(x+iy)=(x,y+1)$ for all complex numbers with modulus $|x+iy|=1 $,i.e.the image of $f$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ with centre $(0,1)$.Then clearly $X=S^1$ is a compact manifold and $Y$ is a manifold and $f:X\to Y$ is a smooth map and $f\not \pitchfork Z$.But if we take the homotopy $f_s(x+iy)=(x,y-s+1) $ where $s\in [0,1]$.Then note that for all values of $s\in (0,1]$, $f_s \pitchfork Z$.So ,this might lead to a common error.One might think that even though $f_s$ is transversal to $Z$,the function $f_0=f$ is not transversal to $Z$.But notice that this does not violate our statement about stability of transversality.Because our starting function in this case is the function $f_0=f$ which is not transversal to $Z$,and keep in mind that our theorem says nothing about what may happen when $f_0$ is homotoped.Notice however that if $g(x+iy)=(x,y)$ with $g_1:S^1\to \mathbb R^2$,and $g$ is homotoped via $g_s(x+iy)=(x,y+s)$,then there indeed exists small enough perturbation tolerence $\epsilon$ for parameter $s$,which preserves the transversality as $s\in [0,\epsilon)$.

PS:
I have edited the question based on the comment of Ted Shifrin and I have changed the example I gave earlier,to avoid any kind of confusion and yet maintaining the flavour of my argument.
Is whatever pointed above a correct understanding of stability?

For starters, a closed interval is not a compact manifold. It is a manifold with boundary. The theorem you’re wanting comes regarding genericity, not stability. Keep reading. But you can modify your example to use this to illustrate why $Z$ must be a closed submanifold (no boundary). Do you see how?

@TedShifrin Yeah,You are absolutely right!I have made an edit in my question.Now can you see if it is Alright?

@TedShifrin (Regarding 'genericity vs stability')Yes I wanted to clarify the distinction between these two concepts as they are close enough and many people might mix up/confuse between them.Exactly the objective of mine behind posting this question!

Obviously, Theorems only apply when their assumptions are satisfied. You said it yourself: "But notice that this does not violate our statement". There is barely anything much to say.

@TedShifrin Actually the doubt arose to one of my students whom I was teaching online,he asked me that we can just take the reverse homotopy $g_s=f_{1-s}$ ,but that was not at all correct,so I thought it should be highlighted for beginners.

Actually, when I taught this material numerous times, I defined stability not in terms of homotopy (which, as you point out, is an asymmetric notion) but rather in terms of arbitrary families of maps parametrized by an open subset $S\subset\Bbb R^N$. But, again, I don't know why you (or your student) insist(s) on confusing a statement and its inverse. :) I have never found this to be a common misinterpretation.

@TedShifrin Maybe this is a critical misconception which is sparse(measure $0$) like critical values of smooth function. ;)
